# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2 +x} -3}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2 +x} -3}$$

I don't know what to do after this point. Also, the limit laws do not make sense to me when it comes to radicals or fractions. Do I evaluate now and treat the root as a fraction, thus it will be $0$? And what do I do with the $+3x$. Does it go in front of the limit ($3 \lim x$) and is being multiplied by the $3$ times infinity?

What is really happening?

Comment: The minus 3 is in the denominator, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2(9 +\frac{1}{x})} -x\frac{3}{x}} =\lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{x}{x\sqrt{(9 +\frac{1}{x})} -x\frac{3}{x}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{(9 +\frac{1}{x})} -\frac{3}{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{9}} = \frac{1}{3}$$
since both $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{3}{x}$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: How are you factoring out the x^2?

Comment: yes, I am... Also I have no problem about the sign since the limit is for $x \to +\infty$, then $x$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

We have

\begin{align*}
& \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{9 x^2 + x} - 3} \\
& =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{9 + \frac{1}{x}} - \frac{3}{x}} \\
& = \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Be careful.  You have to divide each term in the numerator and denominator by $x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{9x^2+x}+3$, and everything should work out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\dfrac1x=h$

$$F=\lim_{x\to\infty}   \frac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2 +x} -3}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac1{h\left[\sqrt{9/h^2+1/h}-3\right]}$$

As $h>0,$

$$F=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac1{\sqrt{9+h}-3h}=\frac1{\sqrt9-0}=\cdots$$